# How do I implement clickable windows on markers using Angular Google Maps?

Tags: angularjs, angular-google-maps

I have tried this every-which-way and still no luck. Please bear with me, I am a designer by trade.

I have created a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/XJPTfvor9RLedMBiqnCI?p=preview) of where I am so far.

I am using [Angular Google Maps](https://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/) to create a map upon which I would like to output my markers, clicking one of which will open its info-window. Within each info window I would like to have some interactive content e.g. buttons, links, marching bands etc

My problem is multi-faceted:

1. When I place the info window html inside the  tag none of the variables are displayed unless a ng-non-bindable is placed on a parent. However, I want the content to be interactive. As you will see in my code, the button does nothing.

   ```
   <ui-gmap-windows show="show">
       <div class="markerwindow" ng-non-bindable>
           <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
           <p>{{ message }}</p>
           <footer>
               <a href="http://foo-bar.com">Google</a>
               <button click="buttonClick(id)">Button</button>
           </footer>
       </div>
   </ui-gmap-windows>
   ```
2. I cannot separate the template out into a separate file [I expect the info window to end up being pretty significant] using templateUrl on the  without this error:

   > "Possibly unhandled Error: error within chunking iterator: Error:
   >   [jqLite:nosel] Looking up elements via selectors is not supported by
   >   jqLite!"

   ```
   <ui-gmap-windows show="show" templateUrl="templates/window.html">
   </ui-gmap-windows>
   ```
3. Finally, I weep to myself sometimes when I read documentation...

Could someone help me identify the issues with my approach? I would really appreciate even a flake of help because I'm really struggling to see a way over this obstacle at the moment.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `templateURL` attribute is a property on your marker object. Here is some code I'm currently working on:

```
function createMarkers(data) {
  $scope.markers = data.map(function(marker){
    var tags = marker.tags.map(function(tag){
      return {
        tag: tag.tag,
        url: tag.url
      }
    })
    return ({
      id: marker.id,
      latitude: marker.position.lat,
      longitude: marker.position.lng,
      info: {
        title: marker.item,
        description: marker.note,
        place: marker.position.place,
        tags: tags
      },
      template: "views/partials/main/gmapWindow.html"
    })
  })
}
```

As you can see I have a property named `template` that contains an url to a template (partials might not be the best naming...). Also note that I have a property called `info` that contains stuff like `title` and `description`.

My `ui-gmap-google-map`-directive looks like this:

```
<ui-gmap-google-map center='map.center' zoom='map.zoom'>
  <ui-gmap-markers models="markers" coords="'self'" icon="'icon'">
    <ui-gmap-windows
      templateUrl="'template'"
      templateParameter="'info'"
      show="'showWindow'"
      closeClick="'closeClick'"
    ></ui-gmap-windows>
  </ui-gmap-markers>
</ui-gmap-google-map>
```

Note that I use both `"` as well as `'` in `templateUrl` and `templateParameter`. `templateUrl` is the property that contains a string to a template (this way we can use different template for different markers) and `templateParameter` is also a property in the markers-model. That property contains an object that we pass into the template.

Finally we can create our template and access the object that we passed into it, in my case the `info`-object that where a property on the model.

```
<div>
    <h3>{{ :: parameter.title }}</h3>
    <p><em>{{ :: parameter.description }}</em></p>
    <p><strong>{{ :: parameter.place }}</strong></p>
    <p class="muted">Tags: <tags marker="{{ :: parameter.tags }}" /></p>
</div>
```

Oh, and I weep as well when reading the documentation...

Comment: I had to dust off the project but your answer seems legit. Great help, thanks.

Comment: Great! My first answer! :) I where struggling with the same thing when I came across your question so I thought I would answer anyway just in case someone else found the question.